# [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: auth]

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am pretty new to React Native; I have been trying to add google authentication via firebase and I keep running into this warning:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: auth]
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:86:13 in tryCatch
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:66:31 in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:86:13 in tryCatch
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:124:27 in invoke
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:148:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:147:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:152:154 in _invoke
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\regeneratorRuntime.js:238:57 in exports.async
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:177:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:437:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:132:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:131:4 in flushedQueue
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import * as Google from "expo-google-app-auth";

import{
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithCredential,
  signOut,
} from "@firebase/auth";


const AuthContext = createContext({});

const config = {
  androidClientId: key,
  iosClientId: key,
  scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
  permissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'gender', 'location'],
}

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
      await Google.logInAsync(config).then(async (logInResult) => {
        if(logInResult.type === 'success'){
            const { idToken, accessToken }  = logInResult;
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);

            await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
        }

        return Promise.reject();
      });
  };

    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value ={{
          user: null,
          signInWithGoogle
      }}
      >
        {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

I pass the variable auth here:

```
await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
```

However, no users show up on the authentication page of firebase, and I keep receiving this warning.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where do you declare this variable?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you're trying to pass an `auth` variable to `signInWithCredential`, but you don't declare or initialize it anywhere. As shown in the documentation on [getting started with Firebase Authentication on the web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start), you can get this with:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official documentation provided by firebase for [google auth](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#google)

The [google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) library provides a wrapper around the official Google login library, allowing you to create a credential and sign-in to Firebase.

Most configuration is already setup when using Google Sign-In with Firebase, however you need to ensure your machines SHA1 key has been configured for use with Android. You can see how to generate the key on the [Getting Started](https://rnfirebase.io/) documentation.

Ensure the "Google" sign-in provider is enabled on the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers).

Follow these instructions to install and setup `google-signin`

Before triggering a sign-in request, you must initialize the Google SDK using your any required scopes and the `webClientId`, which can be found in the `android/app/google-services.json` file as the `client/oauth_client/client_id` property (the id ends with `.apps.googleusercontent.com`). Make sure to pick the `client_id` with `client_type: 3`

```js
    import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
    
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      webClientId: '',
    });
```

Once initialized, setup your application to trigger a sign-in request with Google using the `signIn` method.

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { Button } from 'react-native';
    
    function GoogleSignIn() {
      return (
        <Button
          title="Google Sign-In"
          onPress={() => onGoogleButtonPress().then(() => console.log('Signed in with Google!'))}
        />
      );
    }
```

The `onGoogleButtonPress` can then be implemented as follows:

```js
    import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
    import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
    
    async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
      // Get the users ID token
      const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    
      // Create a Google credential with the token
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    
      // Sign-in the user with the credential
      return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
    }
```

Upon successful sign-in, any [onAuthStateChanged](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#listening-to-authentication-state) listeners will trigger with the new authentication state of the user.